# Multiple instances of the same option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, qtip

I'm passing options to the qTip plugin like so:

```
hide: { 
        when: { 
            event: 'unfocus',
            event: 'inactive',
            event: 'click' 
        },
},
```

It appears to be working but should I bundle those 'events' somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the qTip case specifically, it the `inactve` event is special and binds all of the others, it's best to just use it that way, like this:

```
hide: { 
    when: { 
        event: 'inactive'
    }
},
```

Or just:

```
hide: { when: 'inactive' },
```